# How to use npm module in a web project without know node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, persian-calendar

I am and ASP.Net developer and not familiar with node.js.

I found the following npm module which is a very nice date picker and I want to use it:

[Persian Date & Time Picker For Vue.js](http://www.vuescript.com/persian-date-time-picker-vue-js/)

How can I make a simple **.js** file to include in my html file and use this date picker without going through node.js like when I use bootstrap?

I'm in a project and I cannot learn node.js right now.

Comment: If it is not possible please guide me about what should I learn to be able to use this plugin.

Comment: my question is completely specific.
I want to use a node module with a simple include of an .js file because I don't know about node.js and answer from @Benjamin is completely right and I used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Just Including a .js file

You can use a tool like browserify's CDN in order to convert the file into a .js file and get:

```
https://wzrd.in/standalone/vue-persian-datetime-picker@latest
```

You can then include it in a script tag:

```
<script src='https://wzrd.in/standalone/vue-persian-datetime-picker@latest'></script>
```

Which would define a `window.vuePersianDatetimePicker` property you can use.

### What you *should probably* do

You don't need to *know* Node.js or use it in your backend in order to use a frontend NPM component. Knowing helps but it's not a must.

Note that the Vue CLI and other related tools are all Node programs.

Node isn't scary (promise), it's not easy and takes time to learn to use well - but as someone who does both Node.js and ASP.net a lot of the concepts map nicely.

You'd:

#### Use Vue from the CLI

See [installing the CLI](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/README.md#cli) if you don't have it installed.

```
vue create my-project
```

This means you initialize vue from the CLI (or do manual set up - which would require learning webpack).

In practice - almost no one ever includes Vue as a `<script>` tag since you need a lot of surrounding code anyway (like making all the files into a single file - bundling).

#### Install the module

NPM is the NuGet of the JavaScript world - it's also much much bigger.

```
npm install vue-persian-datetime-picker --save
```

#### Import it in your code

```
import VuePersianDatetimePicker from 'vue-persian-datetime-picker'
```

Here, the fact we `npm install`ed the module means we can `import` it.

Comment: I used the first approach with wzrd.in and got the object. 
Now I get another error. 
I updated my question.
please help me.

Comment: @OmidSadeghi it doesn't work this way (StackOverflow). You don't change the question _after_ you've asked it.

Comment: so what should I do now?
should I ask a new question?

Comment: Yes, very specifically and with an [mcve].